# Can Zend Server co-exist?

Tags: zend-framework

I need to install and start using Zend server. The problem is that I have many clients' projects already on that server, including many done in Codeigniter. From what I have seen using Zend on another client's box, it takes over php. Can I install Zend server on a server and trigger it with the main index file like CI does? I can't take the chance on my other sites going down... Is there a reference somewhere on this? I couldn't find it... Thanks!

Comment: Zend Server and Zend Framework are two very different things. Could you clarify which one you are referring to?

Comment: I want to develop sites using the Zend Framework. But I don't need the auto-generation tools and such. I can do that by hand. I also want access to the framework and the libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment it seems you mean Zend Framework rather than Zend Server. ZF is just a collection of PHP classes. If you want to build some ZF applications you can drop ZF into those without affecting your other sites.

Zend Server on the other hand is an alternative to installing a LAMP stack (or equivalent) yourself. You do not need Zend Server to use Zend Framework.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware. I just want to build apps using the framework.  Guess I can skip the server install.